# Jenkins issue with checkouts from remote Git repository

Tags: git, ssh, jenkins

I have Jenkins v1.500 installed on a Windows 7 Pro box along with Git v1.8.1.msysgit.1

We have recently installed Git v1.7.1 on a remote Linux box,

SSH has been setup and works when remoting to the Git machine.

Jenkins is failing with the following errors using git.exe;

```
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git clone --progress -o origin ssh:///git@10.200.47.202:/home/git/vc_vnv.git D:\Jenkins\jobs\Compile_JBoss_Crawler\workspace" returned status code 128:
stdout: Cloning into 'D:\Jenkins\jobs\Compile_JBoss_Crawler\workspace'...

stderr: Using username "git-upload-pack '/git".
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

I'm noticing an extra / up there, and if I run the command from CMD without the extra /, we get the repo!

**Does anyone have any idea about the cause of the extra '/', or how I can fix it?**

I'll appreciate any advice or tips!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: is it `C:\Users\USERNAME.ssh` or `C:\Users\USERNAME\.ssh` ?

Comment: Good call Albert, the '\' got edited out, I'll stick it back in!

Comment: I had a similar problem. Please check if you have `%HOME%` pointing to `%USERPROFILE%` (C:\Users\USERNAME)

Comment: Just did an ENV from a jenkins job;HOME=/c/Users/USERNAME

Comment: Not sure it is the same. Try `echo %HOME%` from the Jenkins machine command.

Comment: C:\Users\USERNAME>echo %HOME%
C:\Users\USERNAME

I admire your persistence, but I assure you the SSH is all working properly. I'm able to SSH USER@GIT_IP from CMD without any prompts

Comment: What user is Jenkins service running under?

Comment: From the service viewer, I see Jenkins runs as DOMAIN\USERNAME. The same username where the .ssh folder is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AH! At this point Jenkins and Git are cooperating! I seemed to be having issues using putty for the SSH. I had read that what came packaged with Git was problematic, and that putty should be used in its place. However, after removing the GIT_SSH environment variable pointing to putty, the jobs are building again!

Answer (score -1):

In our case we had the server connected both by ethernet and wifi to the network.

Deactivating WiFi fixed the problem, although Ethernet was higher in priority under Network/Preferences (Mac mini OS X).

Comment: The `PHY` layer is very much abstracted from `APPLICATION` layer...this answer is irrelevant.

Comment: It should. Yet this DO fixed our problem (OS X/Jenkins bug?). Wifi on and connected -> no luck. WiFi off -> works.

Comment: @Rivera..So you are saying that if you kept `Wifi` and `Ethernet` ON you see this error described in question otherwise you don't?

Comment: Exactly. In the morning I noticed the server had its Wifi off all the time. Turned it on and connected making sure ethernet was first in priority. In the afternoon these errors started to appear. Landed in this page with no answers. Before trying something else I turned WiFi back off and the problem was solved. I didn't investigate further and just posted my experience.